# SIgnal to noise measurement on iOS7

Tags: ios7, signal-processing

I am using AVAudiosession in iOS7 to study the input from an external mic. I can get values for average power and peak power of the signal using:

```
[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]
```

What I am looking for is a way to calculate the SNR for this channel (calculating P(noise))? I want to be able to make recommendations to the person taking the test based on their environment and the noise detected in it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Measure the power with and without the signal present, take the ratio, and perhaps average over several measurement cycles.